# C : Input interval and then out only even numbers (2,4,6,8...)

Tags: c

I need some program who after interval input show only even numbers and then all these number multiplying and to screen shows result.

For example,

```
Input 2 and 7
Output 2 4 6 
And 2*4*6
End Result = 48
```

About the code ,this is all what I have. I dont know with what to begin. Im new in C language :(

```
int m, n;
n = 0;
m = 0;
clrscr();
printf("Write first number");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("Write second number");
scanf("%d", &n);

if(n <=0 || m <= 0 || n < m || n==m){
    printf("ERROR");
}
```

Thank you for help! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: First write a program that outputs every other number in an interval (it's one loop). Then write a program that multiplies every other number in an interval and prints the result (it's one loop follwed by an output). Then combine the two programs into one loop followed by an output. Then adjust your starting point so it's even. Then you're done.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = m;
int result = 1;

if (i%2 != 0) i++; // increase start by one when it's not even

for(; i <= n; i += 2) {  // increment i by 2 after every loop
        result *= i;
}
printf("%d", result);
```

something like this would be easier to read for beginners i guess:

```
int i;
int result = 1;
for(i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            result *= i;
        }
}
printf("%d", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a for-loop :

```
for (i = m; i < n; i += 2)
    end_result *= i;
```

To check if a number is even you can use the `%` operator.

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
```

Something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int m = 1, n = 7, end_result = 1, i = 0;

    if (m % 2 != 0)
        m++;

    for (i = m; i <= n; i += 2) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        end_result *= i;
    }

    printf("\nThe result is %d\n\n", end_result);

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
>  2 4 6
>  The result is 48
> ```

Comment: the OP writes `pair`, which means even, divisible by two.  if the first number input is odd, you should start from the next one: input `3 7` -> `4 * 6 = 24`

Comment: @chqrlie I'm sorry, English is not my native language and I didn't know the meaning of even

Comment: @ClaudioCortese: That's quite alright, it may seem odd to you, but *odd* means *impair*, not divisible by two.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right, that seems very odd to me. :'D

Comment: I updated your answer

Answer (score 0):

What you need to complete this task is "for" loop inside of which you will have an if statement that will check for parity. An integer x is even when dividing modulo by 2 results with 0. You can get modulo in C by using % operator.

```
if (x % 2 == 0) {
    // x is even
}
```